# How to get the value of $a + b + c$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

$(0 \leq a  < b < c) \in Z$,

$a + b + c + ab + ac + bc + abc = 1622$

$a + b + c = ?$

I've assumed that $a = 0$, by that we can get rid of this part $ab + ac + abc$

Now $bc + b + c = 1622$.

But I found that was useless and got stuck.

Comment: Hint: $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

$$a+b+c+ab+ac+bc+abc=(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)-1$$

Therefore $(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)=?$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$1+a+b+c+ab+bc+ca+abc=(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)$$
$$(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)=1623=1\cdot3\cdot541$$
$$\implies a=0,\ b=2,\ c=540.$$
Note that $0\leq a<b<c$. Those three numbers, 1, 3 and 541 are the only possible factorisation that could satisfy this criteria